# How to run a thread in the WorkManager when triggered by the TimerManager

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, websphere, workmanagers

**Background:** I use Spring 3.0.x in my Websphere 7 applications to grab the CommonJ WorkManager and TimerManager. I use these to do arbitrary tasks at certain intervals in my deployed applications.

**Background 2:** This is a follow-up question to a previous one I had (poorly titled) wondering if a thread triggered from the TimerManager was actually run by the TimerManager thread pool or from the WorkManager thread pool (it ended up being the TimerManager thread pool).  *Previous question: [Getting Spring scheduled tasks to run with the task executor thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766170)*

**Question:**

Is there a simple or elegant way, using Spring or some other method, to run a thread in the WorkManager thread pool when it is triggered from the TimerManager?

I prefer a Spring solution because it is more container-neutral.

Thanks!